# how to get street level information using Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Map API and i want to integrate Google Map API with my         application.I developed code for address from the postcode but its give me only one record but i have checked on other site who provide this kind of facility. They  will get 46 records,Please help me to get out of this.For demo purpose i am using 'IP27 0HP' this as a postcode which is in  UK. I have searched lots of things but even i am not finding in Google API documentation which return me county, town, street and address line 1, address line 2 etc..

Comment: Are you saying you want the 46 postal addresses for which `IP27 0HP` is the postcode?

Comment: 'IP27 0HP' is a postcode, Actually i am getting response from Google Map API : like Brandon, Suffolk IP27 0HP, UK but i need  address list from 1 to 46 Walton Way,Brandon, Suffolk IP27 0HP, UK, here is a link you enter this postcode and find the result :http://www.simply-postcode-lookup.com/for_web.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google cannot provide multiple address information for a single postcode.**

The Royal Mail own postcode data, and while they have been forced to release geographic information (so Google can provide a location given a postcode), address data is not released and not available from any other provider.

Your example site has access to PAF (the Royal Mail Postal Address File) which contains this data. It's not free, which is why that site charges. They have to cover their own licence cost.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Since last fives days i am trying to get this response but i was fail but you gave a clear guidance.